# Geth node: How long it will take to complete "State healing in progress"

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, state

```
Jul 06 17:30:38 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:30:38.945] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=86762@4.29MiB        slots=112,610@8.11MiB         codes=334@2.06MiB        nodes=666,728@175.06MiB pending=27803
Jul 06 17:30:48 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:30:48.614] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=86784@4.30MiB        slots=112,612@8.11MiB         codes=335@2.06MiB        nodes=666,892@175.12MiB pending=28209
Jul 06 17:30:56 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:30:56.727] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=86810@4.30MiB        slots=112,620@8.11MiB         codes=335@2.06MiB        nodes=667,007@175.15MiB pending=28269
Jul 06 17:31:05 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:31:05.660] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=86838@4.30MiB        slots=112,647@8.11MiB         codes=335@2.06MiB        nodes=667,193@175.20MiB pending=28338
Jul 06 17:31:14 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:31:14.587] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=86873@4.30MiB        slots=112,677@8.11MiB         codes=335@2.06MiB        nodes=667,387@175.25MiB pending=28357
Jul 06 17:31:22 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:31:22.931] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=86919@4.30MiB        slots=112,706@8.11MiB         codes=335@2.06MiB        nodes=667,582@175.29MiB pending=28315
Jul 06 17:31:34 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:31:34.195] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=86985@4.31MiB        slots=112,729@8.12MiB         codes=336@2.06MiB        nodes=667,870@175.35MiB pending=28501
Jul 06 17:31:42 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:31:42.328] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=87036@4.31MiB        slots=112,744@8.12MiB         codes=336@2.06MiB        nodes=668,064@175.39MiB pending=28488
Jul 06 17:31:54 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:31:54.473] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=87083@4.31MiB        slots=112,757@8.12MiB         codes=336@2.06MiB        nodes=668,285@175.45MiB pending=28497
Jul 06 17:32:13 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:32:13.423] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=87112@4.31MiB        slots=112,769@8.12MiB         codes=336@2.06MiB        nodes=668,544@175.52MiB pending=28666
Jul 06 17:32:39 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:32:39.392] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=87148@4.31MiB        slots=112,782@8.12MiB         codes=336@2.06MiB        nodes=668,868@175.62MiB pending=28958
Jul 06 17:33:05 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:33:05.021] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=87168@4.32MiB        slots=112,794@8.12MiB         codes=336@2.06MiB        nodes=669,098@175.71MiB pending=29230
Jul 06 17:33:23 65-109-20-116.ptr geth[559458]: INFO [07-06|17:33:23.234] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=87182@4.32MiB        slots=112,806@8.12MiB         codes=336@2.06MiB        nodes=669,281@175.78MiB pending=29511
```

Can anyone explain me how long it will take to finish syncing?
Or just let me know it can be finished or not.

Thanks.